# Could not execute command /usr/bin/bash

Tags: bash, xmonad, xmobar

I am trying to show volume on my xmobar using the method [here](https://gist.github.com/Dnomyar/9c289fcc2668b59e1ffb):

```
    Config { font = "xft:Ubuntu Mono:pixelsize=16:antialias=true:hinting=true"
            , borderColor = "black"
            , border = TopB
            , bgColor = "black"
            , fgColor = "grey"
            , position = TopP 0 0
            , commands = [ 
                    Run Date "%a %_d.%_m  %H:%M" "date" 10
                    , Run StdinReader
                    , Run Com "/usr/bin/bash" ["-c", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"]  "myvolume" 1
            ]
            , sepChar = "%"
            , alignSep = "}{"
            , template = "<fc=#FFF>%StdinReader%</fc>}{<fc=#FFF>%date%</fc> -- %myvolume%"
            }
```

But instead of showing volume I get this message in my xmobar:

> Could not execute command /usr/bin/bash

I tried replacing `/usr/bin/bash` with `/bin/bash` and just `bash` but with the same results

does anyone know what the problem is ?

When I run this in the terminal, it works fine:

```
$ bash ~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh 
Vol: 16%
```

---

output of `$type bash` is

> bash is hashed (/usr/bin/bash)

---

result of `grep -3i execv sux` following `strace -s <PID> -fp -o sux`

```
98743 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98743
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
98743 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98743 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
97272 close(11 <unfinished ...>
--
98744 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98744 close(11)                         = 0
98744 close(10)                         = 0
98744 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98744
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98744 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98744 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98745 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98745 close(11)                         = 0
98745 close(10)                         = 0
98745 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98745
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98745 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98745 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98746 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98746 close(11)                         = 0
98746 close(10)                         = 0
98746 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98746
97272 close(6)                          = 0
98746 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98746 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
--
98747 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98747 close(11)                         = 0
98747 close(10)                         = 0
98747 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98747
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98747 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... close resumed>)              = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98747 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98748 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98748 close(11)                         = 0
98748 close(10)                         = 0
98748 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98748
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98748 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98748 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98749 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98749 close(11)                         = 0
98749 close(10)                         = 0
98749 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98749
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98749 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
98749 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
--
98750 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98750 close(11)                         = 0
98750 close(10)                         = 0
98750 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98750
97272 close(6)                          = 0
98750 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98750 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
--
98751 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98751 close(11)                         = 0
98751 close(10)                         = 0
98751 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98751
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98751 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
98751 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
--
98752 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98752 close(11)                         = 0
98752 close(10)                         = 0
98752 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98752
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98752 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
98752 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98753 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98753 close(11)                         = 0
98753 close(10)                         = 0
98753 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98753
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98753 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98753 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98754 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98754 close(11)                         = 0
98754 close(10)                         = 0
98754 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98754
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98754 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
98754 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
--
98755 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98755 close(11)                         = 0
98755 close(10)                         = 0
98755 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98755
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98755 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... close resumed>)              = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98755 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98756 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98756 close(11)                         = 0
98756 close(10)                         = 0
98756 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98756
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98756 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... close resumed>)              = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98756 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98757 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98757 close(11)                         = 0
98757 close(10)                         = 0
98757 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98757
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98757 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98757 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98758 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98758 close(11)                         = 0
98758 close(10)                         = 0
98758 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98758
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98758 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... close resumed>)              = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98758 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98759 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98759 close(11)                         = 0
98759 close(10)                         = 0
98759 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98759
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98759 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98759 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98760 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98760 close(11)                         = 0
98760 close(10)                         = 0
98760 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98760
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98760 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98760 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98761 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98761 close(11)                         = 0
98761 close(10)                         = 0
98761 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98761
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98761 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98761 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98762 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98762 close(11)                         = 0
98762 close(10)                         = 0
98762 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98762
97272 close(6)                          = 0
98762 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98762 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
--
98763 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98763 close(11)                         = 0
98763 close(10)                         = 0
98763 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98763
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98763 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98763 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98764 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98764 close(11)                         = 0
98764 close(10)                         = 0
98764 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98764
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98764 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98764 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98765 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98765 close(11)                         = 0
98765 close(10)                         = 0
98765 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98765
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98765 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98765 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98766 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98766 close(11)                         = 0
98766 close(10)                         = 0
98766 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98766
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98766 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
98766 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
--
98767 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98767 close(11)                         = 0
98767 close(10)                         = 0
98767 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98767
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98767 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
98767 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98768 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98768 close(11)                         = 0
98768 close(10)                         = 0
98768 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98768
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98768 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98768 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98769 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98769 close(11)                         = 0
98769 close(10)                         = 0
98769 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98769
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98769 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98769 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98770 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98770 close(11)                         = 0
98770 close(10)                         = 0
98770 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98770
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98770 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98770 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98771 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98771 close(11)                         = 0
98771 close(10)                         = 0
98771 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98771
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98771 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98771 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98772 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98772 close(11)                         = 0
98772 close(10)                         = 0
98772 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98772
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98772 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98772 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98773 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98773 close(11)                         = 0
98773 close(10)                         = 0
98773 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98773
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
98773 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
97272 close(11 <unfinished ...>
98773 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98774 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98774 close(11)                         = 0
98774 close(10)                         = 0
98774 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98774
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98774 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(11)                         = 0
98774 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98775 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98775 close(11)                         = 0
98775 close(10)                         = 0
98775 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98775
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98775 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... close resumed>)              = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98775 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98776 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98776 close(11)                         = 0
98776 close(10)                         = 0
98776 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98776
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98776 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... close resumed>)              = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98776 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98777 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98777 close(11)                         = 0
98777 close(10)                         = 0
98777 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98777
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98777 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... close resumed>)              = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98777 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98778 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98778 close(11)                         = 0
98778 close(10)                         = 0
98778 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98778
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98778 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
98778 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98779 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98779 close(11)                         = 0
98779 close(10)                         = 0
98779 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98779
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
98779 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 close(9)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(8, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98779 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
--
98780 dup2(11, 2)                       = 2
98780 close(11)                         = 0
98780 close(10)                         = 0
98780 execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"], 0x7fff9c760fc0 /* 45 vars */ <unfinished ...>
97272 <... vfork resumed>)              = 98780
97272 close(6)                          = 0
97272 fcntl(7, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC <unfinished ...>
98780 <... execve resumed>)             = 0
97272 <... fcntl resumed>)              = 0
97272 close(9 <unfinished ...>
98780 brk(NULL <unfinished ...>
```

Comment: Looks to be a quite mysterois problem. There could be various reasons. I do not know xmobar, but imho you should trace, what it exactly tries to do. Run a `strace -s 4096 -fp -o sux -p <pid>` where `<pid>` is your xmobar. It will generate a kernel call trace of your xmobar process in the file named "sux". Then reproduce the problem with it. Then stop the tracing, and search for the "execv" string in your "sux" file (`grep -3i execv sux``). If you can do these all, then copy the output here into your question.

Comment: @peterh I added the result, not sure if I did it right though - you can see how I ran the command in updated question

Comment: Thank you for the strace output -- it was immensely helpful in understanding what was going on here.

Comment: BTW, I'd strongly suggest not passing `bash` as an explicit interpreter at all. If you have your script as an executable file with a proper shebang (like `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/usr/bin/bash` or so forth as the first line), you should be able to use `Run Com "/home/youruser/.config/xmobar/get-volume"`, and let the operating system identify the interpreter to use from the shebang line.

Comment: ...see [Commandname Extensions Considered Harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/) re: why the above suggestion drops the `.sh`. (Whereas if you were going to source the file rather than executing it, I would suggest changing the extension to `.bash` so it actually matches with the specific shell syntax variant the script is run with).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks! There is a correct bash execution here. The cause of the problem was the tilde, as the accepted answer says. This had been visible in the strace output (strace also tracks the bash execution), but our grep filtered it out.

Comment: @peterh, yup, I'm the author of that accepted answer, so I do know that. :)

Comment: @peterh, ...the point of dropping the explicit invocation of the shell is separate from the answer (which is just about providing the shortest possible suggestion that makes it work), and is rather a matter of futureproofing / good practice. If you rewrite something to be in a non-bash language, letting the OS pick the interpreter lets you just change the file with the script itself and not have to also change the configuration code invoking that executable. And distinguishing `.sh` / `.bash` is also so future-you knows what the compatibility constraints are when you look at the code later.

Comment: (_having_ an extension is a signal to readers that the script is going to be sourced or executed with a specific interpreter; `.sh` indicates that that interpreter is guaranteed only to be something in the POSIX sh family, `.bash` indicates that it's specifically bash, whereas having no extension at all indicates to readers that the shebang is the only supported way to do interpreter selection and that the tool can be rewritten in a different language without needing to modify callers).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy for a great explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tilde is replaced with the appropriate directory by the calling shell (when that tilde is present in an unquoted context as part of the source code the shell is executing). There is no calling shell here, only a called one; and the tilde is data, not syntax.

So change...

```
"~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"
```

to:

```
"/home/youraccount/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"
```

...*or*, to:

```
"-c", ". ~/.config/xmobar/get-volume.sh"
```

(which makes the argument following the `-c` be parsed as shell syntax, wherein a `~` is subject to replacement).